# ¿Cómo crear un diccionario con funciones en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente codigo, lo he estado uniendo de diferentes partes ya que estoy aprendiendo este lenguaje....creo un diccionario para llamar a los metodos por medio de una opcion(un case en python)....pero sin ingresar la opcion se me imprime todo lo que esta dentro del diccionario.

```
class Calculadora:
    def __init__(self, uno, dos):
        self.numero = uno
        self.numerito = dos

    def Suma(self):
       print ("La suma de los 2 numeros es: ", (self.numero+self.numerito))

    def Resta(self):
       print ("La resta de los 2 numeros es: ", (self.numero-self.numerito))

    def Multiplicacion(self):
       print ("La multiplicacion de los 2 numeros es: ",(self.numero*self.numerito))

    def Division(self):
        try:
            print("La division de los 2 numeros es  ", (self.numero/self.numerito))
        except Exception:
            print(("No se puede dividir con cero!\n"))


primero=int(input("Inserta un Numero: "))
segundo=int(input("Inserta otro Numero: "))

Objeto=Calculadora(primero,segundo)


print("Operaciones a realizar\n1 - Sumar\n2 - Restar\n3 - Nultiplicar\n4 - Dividir\n")
opcion=input("Seleccione operacion: ")
print(type(opcion))
operaciones = { '1': Objeto.Suma(), '2': Objeto.Resta(), '3': 
Objeto.Multiplicacion(), '4':Objeto.Division()}


##resultado=Calculadora(primero,segundo)
##Objeto.operaciones[opcion]
##print(Objeto.Suma)
##print(resultado.Suma())
##print(operaciones[opcion])
##print(resultado)

##    if (opcion == 1):
##  Objeto.Suma()
##    elif (opcion == 2):
##  Objeto.Resta()
##    elif (opcion == 3):
##  Objeto.Multiplicacion()
##    elif (opcion == 4):
##  Objeto.Division()
##    else:
##  print("Debes elegir o uno o dos\n")
```

Comment: Admito que no conozco python, pero te recomendo [edit] tu pregunta para agregar qué errores tiene este código. _si entendí bien tu pregunta_ sea cual sea el valor, el switch/case no es correcto. Te recomiendo investigar mas sobre cómo crear un swicth case en python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto:

```
operaciones = { '1': Objeto.Suma(), '2': Objeto.Resta(), '3': Objeto.Multiplicacion(), '4':Objeto.Division()}
```

Básicamente lo que hace es crear un diccionario cuyos valores se inicializan con la ejecución de cada una de las funciones. Tal como te comentó @Tecnologer, lo que en realidad debes hacer es crear las referencias a cada función

```
operaciones = { 
'1': Objeto.Suma, 
'2': Objeto.Resta, 
'3': Objeto.Multiplicacion, 
'4': Objeto.Division
}
```

Luego para ejecutarlo:

```
operaciones[opcion]()
```

Answer (score 1):

No soy muy bueno en Python, pero creo que cuando asignas la funcion al diccionario la estas mandando ejecutar.

Tal vez sirva cambiar el `funcion()` por `funcion`, es decir:

```
operaciones = { 
    '1': Objeto.Suma, 
    '2': Objeto.Resta, 
    '3': Objeto.Multiplicacion, 
    '4': Objeto.Division
}
```

P.D.: Creo que tu pregunta esta muy abierta, necesitar enfocarla mas a tu problema.

Comment: Efectivamente, tal y como lo tiene al crear el diccionario ejecuta los métodos de instancia y después los valores del diccionario serán el retorno de estos métodos, `None` en todos los casos. Lo que se desea es guardar la referencia al método no su retorno y por lo tanto no podemos llamar al método usando `()`.